# Is it possible to automatically link to cross-posts?

Tags: feature-request, cross-posting

Is it possible to automatically check if a user also posts the same question on one of the other stackexchange sites? If so, can you provide a link to the other question?

For instance,

- [Reading a file line by line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362959/reading-a-file-line-by-line)
- [Reading line by line in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490607/reading-line-by-line-in-perl)

It is a small step for developpers, but a huge step for people spending time helping others (whilst the question is in fact already solved elsewhere).

Is it also possible to throw fire at cross-posters?

Comment: @gnat The different between [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105847/can-we-automate-detection-of-cross-posting) post and this one is that I am simply suggesting to add a related link to the cross-posts. Admitted, the two are similar and I had not found the supposed dupe you suggest.

Comment: Related: [Add optional cross-site “already asked” link to off-topic close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198478/225745).

Comment: @Molot That post is a bit cluttered. Also, I think a link to the cross-post should be added automatically and not as part of some closing or flagging routine. Thanks for adding it anyway.

Comment: @Private I commented it as related, not flagged as duplicate - I see they are two different things. But now cross-posting is forbidden and thus it's a reason for closure, so unless policy changes we both are talking about the very same link, just different way.